# Pro ASP.net MVC3 framework book by adam freeman and steven sanderson

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having trouble with the pro asp.net mvc 3 framework book. On page 175 Creating the Product Repository.

I have errors: Error    1   'SportsStore.Domain.Concrete.EFProductRepository' does not implement interface member 'SportsStore.Domain.Abstract.IProductRepository.Products.set' 
SportsStore\SportsStore.Domain\Concrete\EFProductRepository.cs  11  18  SportsStore.Domain
#

Error   2   The type or namespace name 'Concrete' does not exist in the namespace 'SportsStore.Domain'\SportsStore.WebUI\Infrastructure\NinjectControllerFactory.cs 11  26  SportsStore.WebUI

This is my repository:

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract; 
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities; 
//using System.Web;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete 
{
    public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
        public IQueryable<Product> Products
        {
            get { return context.Products; }
        }
    } 
}
```

### My Product class which is public:

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Entities 
{
  public class Product
  {
      public int ProductID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public decimal Price { get; set; }
      public string Category { get; set; }
  } 
}
```

### my interface:

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Text; using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Abstract 
{
  public interface IProductRepository
  {
      IQueryable<Product> Products { get; set; }
  } 
}
```

### My EFDBContext class:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities; 
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete 
{
  public class EFDbContext : DbContext 
  {
      //DBset<type>   Property name is Products
      public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
  }
}
```

### My ninjectcontrollerfactory class:

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using System.Web.Routing; 
using Ninject; 
using Moq; 
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract; 
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities; 
using SportsStore.Domain.Concrete;

namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Infrastructure 
{
    public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory 
    {
        private IKernel ninjectKernel;

        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType == null ? null : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {
            //P163 - Add a mock implementation of the IProductRepository Interface
            //Mock<IProductRepository> _mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
            //_mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product> 
            //{
            //    new Product {Name = "Football",Price = 25},
            //    new Product {Name = "Surf Board",Price = 179},
            //    new Product {Name = "Running Shoes",Price = 95},

            //}.AsQueryable());
            //_ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().ToConstant(_mock.Object);


            ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();    //P176 Bind to our Live repository

        }

    } 
}
```

There are 3 projects with references:
SportsStore.Domain
SportsStore.UnitTests =  ref to Moq, Ninject,SportsStore.Domain, SportsStore.WebUI
SportsStore.WebUI = ref to Ninject,SportsStore.Domiain

I have search google and it says add a reference on the SportsStore.Domain project to the WebUI project but when i do this it says it cant because it will cause a circular dependency.

Error 1 and Error 2 above, I don't understand because the interface is implemented and also the namespace is in the NinjectControllerFactory where I am binding the IProductRepository to the interface EFProductRepository

Thanks

Comment: Man IProductRepository Products  property has both getter and setter but EFProductRepository implements only getter. This should solve issue #1.

Comment: Have you checked the Apress website for errata/corrections? http://www.apress.com/9781430234043

Comment: Thank You petro for quick response. Also thank you 5arx for your reply for resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the 'set' away from

```
public interface IProductRepository 
{ 
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

and it should solve your problem